# Passing a method to Run method of Task class

Tags: c#, multithreading

Experimenting with Task in C#, notice a problem in my understanding. I want to create a Task in different way. Here are some ways to create Task.

```
   //Probably standard way is like this.
   Task t0 = Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello 0"); });
   t0.Wait();
```

Other ways to create tasks in C# could be the following ways, some are almost similar, people does not use these, I mentioned here for references only.

```
   Task t_1 = Task.Run(delegate ()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Calling with Delegate");
   });
   t_1.Wait();

  Task t1 = Task.Run(delegate () { Console.WriteLine("Hello 1"); });
  t1.Wait();

  Action a = MethodA;
  Task t2 = Task.Run(a);
  t2.Wait();

  Action a2 = new Action(MethodA);
  Task t22 = Task.Run(a2);
  t22.Wait();
```

My question, can I pass directly a method to Task.Run(..) which return void and does not take any parameter (like MethodA). At least in VS 2015 following code does not compile, what do I miss in my understanding?

```
Task t3 = Task.Run(MethodA);
t3.Wait();

public static void MethodA()
{
    Console.WriteLine("MethodA is being called");    
}
```

I did some experiment with Thread and it looks for Thread following code are valid in VS 2015.

```
var thread5 = new Thread(MethodA);
thread5.Start();
```

Comment: "does not compile", what error message do you get?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  I get the following "'void Program.MethodA()' has the wrong return type"  VS 2015 some how mixing with Func and Action probably, not sure why

Comment: `Task.Run(() => MethodA);`

Comment: @kevintjuh93  I know this work but I am trying to understand why my way does not work, thanks

Comment: Use Lasse's his answer for that part.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not compile, and gives this error message:

> CS0407 'void MethodA()' has the wrong return type

is that parameter type inference picks the wrong parameter type.

The `Task.Run` method has 8 overloads, taking various `Func<...>` and `Action<...>` delegates, as well as various other parameters, the ones that are interesting here are these:

```
Task.Run(Action action);
Task.Run(Func<Task> function);
Task.Run(Func<TResult> function);
Task.Run(Func<Task<TResult>> function);
```

basically the compiler is unable to pick the right one.

Helping the compiler slightly will make the code compile, but if you need to use the `Action` overload, then you must specify, here is one example that does compile:

```
public static Task<int> MethodA()
```

Comment: My target is to use the first one. Why does it pick 2nd one?